# Prop is going as null in Child Component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am setting some permission settings using my useEffect like below, I want to pass down the props to my child components I thought it would be easy but I am stuck because my props as going as null to my child components -
Use State

```
   const [userPermission, setUserPermission] = useState({})
```

```
useEffect(() => {

        axios.post('API_ADDRESS', 'Role_num', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'sessionIDNum'
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                setUserPermission(response.data, () => console.log('userPermission', userPermission));
            });
    }, []);
```

```
   return (
        <div style={{
            padding: '0 8px',
        }}>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(userPermission, null, 2)}</pre>  <---This is printing the complete JSON
            <CaseCard permissionData={userPermission} /> <-- sending {} value for the object
            {/* <SideNav permissionData={userPermission} /> */}
        </div >
    )
}
```

Can somone plz help? I think the initial value of my state is being sent to the child components which is set to {} though I want to send the value as props only after my useEffect sets the value to my state.

Note - I am able to print the complete JSON when I use -

```
{JSON.stringify(userPermission, null, 2)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the response from the API call to a child component after setting it to state you should add this conditional to wait to render the component only when the data exists:

```js
if (userPermission){
        <div style={{
            padding: '0 8px',
        }}>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(userPermission, null, 2)}</pre>  <---This is printing the complete JSON
            <CaseCard permissionData={userPermission} /> <-- sending {} value for the object
            {/* <SideNav permissionData={userPermission} /> */}
        </div >
    )
} else {
  return <div>'Loading..'</div>;
}
```